# Deep Link to a Facebook Page

Tags: android, ios, facebook, deep-linking

I am new to this `Deep Linking` stuff, so I would really appreciate your help.

I have a post on Facebook and i need it to point to a page.
BUT when I open the link on mobile, I need it to send me to the page i want people to like, but in the Facebook App on each phone (mainly iOS and Android).

I already tried `fb://profile/[pageID]` but it doesn't link to the specific page, just newsfeed, inside the app. Also tried `fb://page/[pageID]`.
The good part is that it opens it in the Facebook app.

I feel that I am so close, but I don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

I would really appreciate your suggestions!

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

To deep link to a specific page, use `fb://page/{page_id}` for Android and `fb://profile/{page_id}` for iOS.

Tested on Facebook iOS v57.0 and Android v80.0.0.21.65.

Find your page ID using http://findmyfbid.com

Comment: Works for me, although I had to use https://findmyfbid.in instead of .com version.

Answer (score 1):

if the page ID  you used is a text format (fb://page/example) it will not work (i don't know why)
but if it is a long number it will work like for example fb://page/1111111111